# A very weird problem with localization (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I'm using Web Developer 2010. I just created a resource file lang.resx with different values in english. Then I created a lang.FR-fr.resx with French equivalents. However after tryingto compile, I get

> Error 131 Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed

This is so weird! If I remove FR-fr part, it will work, but there will be no translation of course.

I went to that directory and found out that I don't have al.exe there. I managed to find it in .NET 2 folder, but after copying it didn't help. It throws an exception. I tried to reinstall .NET 4, to install Windows SDK, and it still doesn't work.

Maybe I can somehow get this al.exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by restarting the machine :)